# Error: Braintree API Client Misconfigured: clientToken required. after switching from sandbox to production

Tags: payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, braintree

I have been testing Magento with Braintree and everything was working fine.

Today I tried to switch to production, I changed the Merchant ID and Public/Private Keys, as well as the Merchant Account IDs for each currency in my multisite setup.

Everything seems to be set up ok but when I try to choose a payment method I get 'Sorry, but something went wrong'flashing up briefly followed by an eternal spinning wheel on the page.

[image]

The full JS error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Braintree API Client Misconfigured: clientToken required.
    at i (braintree-2.25.0.min.js:3)
    at Object.o [as _getConfiguration] (braintree-2.25.0.min.js:3)
    at Object.i [as setup] (braintree-2.25.0.min.js:6)
    at Object.setup (adapter.js:50)
    at UiClass.initBraintree (cc-form.js:180)
    at UiClass.onActiveChange (cc-form.js:141)
    at setNested (objects.js:43)
    at Object.nested (objects.js:117)
    at UiClass.set (element.js:301)
    at updateValue (links.js:57)
```

I am using Magento 2.1.11, if anyone has any indication what could be causing this I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the SSL certificate... The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://www.paypalobjects.com will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources.